# Issue with output from an if...else function in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function in Python that would return a colour value after evaluating to a user value. This what I have tried, however, I am not get what I expect, a single colour. I am getting a list of colours. I am new to programming.

```
uservalue = 100000

def colour(m,i):
    if uservalue > (m + i):
        clrs == "red"                  
    elif uservalue < (m - i):
        clrs == "blue"              
    else:
        clrs == "white"         
    return clrs
```

to test I use this input:

```
colour(20000, 3000)
```

output:

```
['red', 'red', 'red', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white']
```

I was looking for one colour returned after evaluation.

Comment: `==` is not the same as `=`

Comment: ... and `clrs` was defined before somewhere else in your code with the value `['red', 'red', 'red', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white']`

Answer (score 0):

```
uservalue = 100000

def colour(m,i):
    if uservalue > (m + i):
        clrs = "red"                  
    elif uservalue < (m - i):
        clrs = "blue"              
    else:
        clrs = "white"         
    return clrs

print(colour(20000, 3000))
```

output will be: `red`

Answer (score 0):

you are almost there. replace == with =. == is referred when checking equality and = is referred when assigning a value to a variable. try below code.

```
uservalue = 100000

def colour(m,i):
    if uservalue > (m + i):
        clrs = "red"                  
    elif uservalue < (m - i):
        clrs = "blue"              
    else:
        clrs = "white"         
    return clrs
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that little error cost me hours and sleep.

Comment: @Celtis you are welcome. If my answer make sense, please upvote